# Python - Is there any way to simplify this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to simplify this code? I need to generate a string of max 10 characters long but so that if a letter is randomly chosen for example (a) the next letter can only contain some letters (not any) . That is, if a letter is randomly received it will depend on the selection of the previous letter.

I want to generate a password but in a way that is understandable in my language (memorable)

I'm trying so far but I'm confused

```
import random

alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "."] # the whole alphabet should be here

letter_a = ["e", "g", "y", "x", "w"]
letter_b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"]
letter_c = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g"]
#... letter_d, letter_e atd...
letter_z = ["z", "x", "w", "b", "c"]

my_choice_one = random.choice(alphabet)

while True:
    my_choice_two = random.choice(alphabet)
    if my_choice_one == "a": #<-- here it would take a transformation
        if my_choice_two not in letter_a:
            my_result = my_choice_one+my_choice_two #<-- here I would use something like this (my_result.append(dict) 
            break
        else:
            continue
    elif my_choice_one == "b":
        if my_choice_two not in letter_b:
            my_result = my_choice_one+my_choice_two
            break
        else:
            continue
    elif my_choice_one == "c":
        if my_choice_two not in letter_c:
            my_result = my_choice_one+my_choice_two
            break
        else:
            continue

# ideally so there doesn't have to be another loop
            
while True:
    my_choice_three = random.choice(alphabet)
    if my_choice_two == "a":
        if my_choice_three not in letter_a:
            my_result = my_choice_one+my_choice_two+my_choice_three
            break
        else:
            continue
    elif my_choice_two == "b":
        if my_choice_three not in letter_b:
            my_result = my_choice_one+my_choice_two+my_choice_three
            break
        else:
            continue
    elif my_choice_two == "c":
        if my_choice_three not in letter_c:
            my_result = my_choice_one+my_choice_two+my_choice_three
            break
        else:
            continue
            
# while (stop for) if my_result in ".":
        
        
print(my_result)
```

Comment: Have a look at Markov Chains

Answer (score 1):

combine `letter_a`..`letter_z` into a dictionary:

```
letter_dict = {'a':letter_a, 'b':letter_b,...
```

Then all of your versions of:

```
    if my_choice_two not in letter_a:
        my_result = my_choice_one+my_choice_two
        break
    else:
        continue
```

collapse to a single:

```
    if my_choice_two not in letter_dict[my_choice_one]:
        my_result = my_choice_one+my_choice_two
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Similarly for the second loop.

Unclear what part of stopping the loop is unknown; you've demonstrated all of the tools necessary.

Comment: I thought I didn't have to create 10 loops. The code is a small part just to give you an idea. Two loops only make me 3 characters and I need up to 10 or the end of the loop when choosing a dot.

Comment: You don't need 10 loops; you need one loop to be executed 10 times (that is, put *it* in a loop).